# Python Scrapy - dynamic HTML, div and span content needed

Tags: python, html, scrapy

So I'm new to Scrapy and am looking to do something which is proving a little too ambitious. I'm hoping somebody out there can help guide me on how to gather and parse the info I'm after from this website.

I need to obtain the following:
label1
4810 (this is generated dynamically)
Business name
Name
Address1
Address2
Address3
Address4
Postcode
0800 111111
me@domain.com

Is this even possible using scrapy?

Many thanks in advance.

```html
<div class="mbg">
  <a href="http://www.domain.com" aria-label="label1"> <span class="nw1">Label13345</span>
  </a>
  <span class="mbg-l">
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/1" title="FBS">4810</a> 
     <img 
       alt="4810"
       title="4810"
       src="http://www.domain.com/image1"></span>
</div>
<div id="bsi-c" class=" bsi-c-uk-bislr">
  <div class="bsi-cnt">
    <div class="bsi-ttl section-ttl">
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <div class="rd-sep"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bsi-bn">Business name</div>
    <div class="bsi-cic">
      <div id="bsi-ec" class="u-flL">
        <span class="bsi-arw"><a href="javascript:;"></a></span>
        <span class="bsi-cdt"><a href="javascript:;">Contact details</a></span>
      </div>
      <div id="e8" class="u-flL bsi-ci">
        <div class="bsi-c1">
          <div>Name</div>
          <div>Address1</div>
          <div>Address2</div>
          <div>Address3</div>
          <div>Address4</div>
          <div>Postcode</div>
        </div>
        <div class="bsi-c2">
          <br></br>
          <div>
            <span class="bsi-lbl">Phone:</span>
            <span>0800 111111</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <span class="bsi-lbl">Email:</span>
            <span>me@domain.com</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: of course it is possible, but you'll have to do the requests that needs to be done (because all the information comes on a request), but to help you you'll have to share the site you want to crawl. Another solution is to use selenium to emulate a browser.

Comment: You want to use for parse only scrapy or you can consider other options such as lxml?

Comment: Ah, that could be an issue - it's part of an internal intranet system. Basically I'm part of a comms team and we maintain a separate contact list, but need to somehow check the info and cross ref. with the data we have to ensure it matches and is current. I think I've bitten off a little more than I can chew.

Comment: I haven't considered LXML. Do you think that would be a better option? I should've explained it's for numerous pages, so I'd be looking at Http://www.intranet/oursites/siteaddress1, http.intranet/oursites/siteaddress2 etc...

Comment: I think lxml as the parser for html best. together with cssselect works very well with the DOM. I want to offer to write in the response example for your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of parsing the already received page might look something like this:

```
import lxml.html

page="""<div><span> . . .</span></div> """
doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page)

# get label1 4810
label = doc.cssselect('.mbg .mbg-l a')[0].text_content()
# get address
addres = doc.cssselect('.u-flL .bsi-c1')[0].text_content()
# get phone
phone = doc.cssselect('.bsi-c2 .bsi-lbl')[0].text_content()
# get mail      
mail = doc.cssselect('.bsi-c2 .bsi-lbl')[1].text_content()
```

if a page must be retrieved from the network can make so:

```
import requests, lxml.html

page  = requests.get('site_.com')
doc   = lxml.html.document_fromstring(page.text)
phone = doc.cssselect('.bsi-c2 .bsi-lbl')[0].text_content()
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, much appreciated.